# Verifying modular sum checksum in c#

Tags: c#, ascii, checksum

I'm working with an embedded system that returns ASCII data that includes (what I believe to be) a [modular sum checksum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum#Modular_sum). I would like to verify this checksum, but I've been unable to do so based on the manufacturers specification. I've also been unable to accomplish the opposite and calculate the same checksum based off the description.

Each response from the device is in the following format:

```
╔═════╦═══════════════╦════════════╦════╦══════════╦═════╗
║ SOH ║ Function Code ║ Data Field ║ && ║ Checksum ║ ETX ║
╚═════╩═══════════════╩════════════╩════╩══════════╩═════╝
```

Example:

```
SOHi11A0014092414220&&FBEA
```

Where SOH is ASCII 1. e.g.

```
#define SOH "\x01"
```

The description of the checksum is as follows:

> The Checksum is a series of four ASCII-hexadecimal characters which provide a check on the integrity of all the characters preceding it, including the control
>   characters. The four characters represent a 16-bit binary count which is the 2's complemented sum of the 8-bit binary representation of the message characters after the parity bit (if enabled) has been cleared. Overflows are ignored. The data integrity check can be done by converting the four checksum characters to the 16-bit
>   binary number and adding the 8-bit binary representation of the message characters to it. The binary result should be zero.

I've tried a few different interpretations of the specification, including ignoring SOH as well as the ampersands, and even the function code. **At this point I must be missing something very obvious in either my interpretation of the spec, or the code I've been using to test.** Below you'll find a simple example (data was taken from a live system), *if it were correct, the lower word in the validate variable would be 0*:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    unchecked
    {
        var data = String.Format("{0}{1}", (char) 1, @"i11A0014092414220&&");
        const string checkSum = "FBEA";

        // Checksum is 16 bit word
        var checkSumValue = Convert.ToUInt16(checkSum, 16);

        // Sum of message chars preceeding checksum
        var mySum = data.TakeWhile(c => c != '&').Aggregate(0, (current, c) => current + c);
        var validate = checkSumValue + mySum;

        Console.WriteLine("Data: {0}", data);
        Console.WriteLine("Checksum: {0:X4}", checkSumValue);
        Console.WriteLine("Sum of chars: {0:X4}", mySum);
        Console.WriteLine("Validation: {0}", Convert.ToString(validate, 2));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

## Edit

While the solution provided by @tinstaafl works for this particular example, it doesn't work when providing a larger record such as the below:

> SOHi20100140924165011000007460904004608B40045361000427DDD6300000000427C3C66000000002200000745B4100045B3D8004508C00042754B900000000042774D8D0000000033000007453240004531E000459F5000420EA4E100000000427B14BB000000005500000744E0200044DF4000454AE000421318A0000000004288A998000000006600000744E8C00044E7200045469000421753E600000000428B4DA50000000&&

```
BA6C
```

Theoretically you could keep incrementing/decrementing a value in the string until the checksum matched, it just so happened that using the character 1 rather than the ASCII SOH control character gave it just the right value, a coincidence in this case.

Comment: Are the lengths of the Function Code / Data Field fixed? 
Are there any ASCII control characters delimiting the input?
With the second example, is the leading 1 part of the SOH, or the start of the function code?

Comment: The length of the function code appears to be fixed, the length of the data field depends on the function code. Some also have a variable number of fixed columns. I've edited the example and removed the 1 that was at the beginning of the message and replaced it with SOH. I put the 1 there to demonstrate that replacing the SOH with 1 was merely a coincidence in the first example.

Comment: I strongly suspect that the spec is incomplete or has an error.  The max value for an 8 bit unsigned binary is 255.  The 2's complement should be the negative value of that.  However the checksum value is less than -255, therefore the 8 bit sum with the overflow discarded, when added to the checksum value, can never equal 0.

Comment: I'm seriously considering that as a possibility as well, though I was hoping that there was a simple mistake in my code ;-). If I come up with an answer one way or the other I will post it.

Comment: After more research I think the devices are very buggy. I'm finding cases where the field lengths do not match (dropping tailing zeroes from the minute field, etc). Sometimes it even tacks that missing zero onto the end. My guess is the checksum is the issue here, rather than my code.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but by using an integer of 1 for the SOH instead of a char value of 1, taking the sum of all the characters and converting the `validate` variable to a 16 bit integer, I was able to get validate to equal 0:

```
var data = (@"1i11A0014092414220&&");
const string checkSum = "FBEA";

// Checksum is 16 bit word
var checkSumValue = Convert.ToUInt16(checkSum, 16);

// Sum of message chars preceeding checksum
var mySum = data.Sum<char>(c => c);
var validate = (UInt16)( checkSumValue + mySum);

Console.WriteLine("Data: {0}", data);
Console.WriteLine("Checksum: {0:X4}", checkSumValue);
Console.WriteLine("Sum of chars: {0:X4}", mySum);

Console.WriteLine("Validation: {0}", Convert.ToString(validate, 2));
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Unfortunately that only seems to work for this particular example, which is one of the weaknesses of this type of checksum. I will edit my question to provide an example of where replacing it with 1 doesn't work.